# Design pattern to get rid of switch/case from enum property

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm currently trying to refactor a method that receives a property name and set it's value:

```
private async Task < Enrichment > ParseEnrichmentNewDataAsync(int leadId, string property, string newValue) {
  var enrichment = await _context.EnrichmentRepository.GetByLeadIdAsync(leadId);
  if (enrichment == null) {
    enrichment = new Enrichment() {
      LeadId = leadId
    };
  }

  Enum.TryParse < PropertyType > (property, out
    var enumProperty);
  switch (enumProperty) {
  case PropertyType.Color:
    enrichment.Color = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.UsedVehicleModel:
    enrichment.UsedModel = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.UsedVehicleYear:
    enrichment.UsedYear = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.UsedVehicleKm:
    enrichment.UsedKm = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.Payment:
    enrichment.Payment = Convert.ToInt32(EnumExtension.GetEnumValueFromDescription < PaymentType > (newValue));
    break;
  case PropertyType.ScheduleDate:
    enrichment.ScheduleDate = DateTime.ParseExact(newValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    break;
  case PropertyType.SchedulePeriod:
    enrichment.SchedulePeriod = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.SchedulePhone:
    enrichment.SchedulePhone = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.PurchaseType:
    enrichment.PurchaseType = newValue;
    break;
  case PropertyType.HasOptInNextJeep:
    enrichment.HasOptInNextJeep = Convert.ToBoolean(newValue);
    break;
  }

  return enrichment;
}
```

Using reflection would work for most of the fields, but some values need to be converted before being assigned.
Is there a design pattern or a better way to improve this code?

Comment: "Better way" depends on a lot of things. Like, why is the property name received as a string in the first place? Just as an example, perhaps it comes from JSON/XML. In that case, the answer would be to use one of the popular, well documented libraries to map JSON/XML to POCOs, which can be set up in a declarative way to perform the conversions you need.

Comment: I'd probably go with a `Dictionary<PropertyType, Action<string>>`.  Look up the property type, and the run the associated action (which could include the conversion code).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `PropertyType` is a numeric 0-based `enum`, you could do this:

```
private static Action<Enrichment, string>[] _propertySetters = new Action<Enrichment, string>[]
{
    // Assuming Color = 0
    (enrichment, value) => enrichment.Color = value,
    // Assuming UsedVehicleYear = 1
    (enrichment, value) => enrichment.UsedVehicleYear = value,
    // Assuming UsedVehicleModel = 2
    (enrichment, value) => enrichment.UsedVehicleModel = value,
    // ...
};

private async Task<Enrichment> ParseEnrichmentNewDataAsync(int leadId, string property, string newValue)
{
     // ...
     Enum.TryParse<PropertyType>(property, out var enumProperty);
     var setter = _propertySetters[(int)enumProperty];
     setter(enrichment, newValue);
     // ...
}
```

You could also do this with a `Dictionary<PropertyType, Action<Enrichment, string>>` instead of a flat array, but if performance is what you're going for, this is unlikely to be better than using `switch ... case` until you get to very large numbers of properties.

Comment: I vote +1 for the Dictionary suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Method should do only one thing. Function ParseEnrichmentNewDataAsync does three things:

1. Gets or creates Enrichment object
2. Converts the specified value if needed
3. Sets property of Enrichment object

It would be better to somehow separate converting from property setting.
I would suggest the EnrichmentPropertySetter class, which encapsulates property setting logic:

```
public abstract class EnrichmentPropertyActionBase
{
    public abstract void SetProperty(Enrichment enrichment, string value);
}

public class EnrichmentPropertyAction<T> : EnrichmentPropertyActionBase
{
    public Action<Enrichment, T> Set { get; set; }
    public Func<string, T> Convert { get; set; }

    public override void SetProperty(Enrichment enrichment, string value)
    {
        Set(enrichment, Convert(value));
    }
}

public class EnrichmentPropertySetter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, EnrichmentPropertyActionBase> _dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, EnrichmentPropertyActionBase>();

    public EnrichmentPropertySetter()
    {
        _dictionary["Color"] = new EnrichmentPropertyAction<string>
        {
            Convert = s => s,
            Set = (e, s) => e.Color = s
        };
        ...
        _dictionary["Payment"] = new EnrichmentPropertyAction<int>
        {
            Convert = s => Convert.ToInt32(EnumExtension.GetEnumValueFromDescription<PaymentType>(s)),
            Set = (e, i) => e.Payment = i
        };
        _dictionary["ScheduleDate"] = new EnrichmentPropertyAction<DateTime>
        {
            Convert = s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Set = (e, d) => e.ScheduleDate = d
        };
        ...
        _dictionary["HasOptInNextJeep"] = new EnrichmentPropertyAction<bool>
        {
            Convert = s => Convert.ToBoolean(s),
            Set = (e, s) => e.HasOptInNextJeep = s
        };
    }

    public void SetProperty(Enrichment enrichment, string property, string value)
    {
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(property, out EnrichmentPropertyActionBase action))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Something goes wrong...");

        action.SetProperty(enrichment, value);
    }
}
```

Assuming that number of properties is limited, I don’t think using Dictionary may lead to significant performance issues.

But this solution is still not ideal, because we have to hardcode property names anyway. Maybe you should think about why you need to set properties by the specified name, and revisit the task.